# Remove all objects containing a specific value from a JSON file using JQ?

Tags: json, jq, vivaldi

The bookmarks file for the Vivaldi browser (based on Chromium) tends to accumulate a huge number of base64-encoded thumbnails taking up a lot of space, and I would like to remove these entries. The file is a JSON file and an entry looks like this:

```
{
  "date_added": "13215828073144281",
  "guid": "3ace3174-ea60-42c5-88cf-e535a150ae38",
  "id": "74",
  "meta_info": {
     "Thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA....AUpSgFKUoBSlKA//2Q=="
  },
  "name": "RIPE WHOIS IP Address Database Search › Look up an IP addres… - iTools",
  "type": "url",
  "url": "http://itools.com/tool/ripe-whois-ip-address"
},
```

I already have a jq filter looking like this:

`jq 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.key | test("Thumbnail") | not)) else . end)' Bookmarks > Bookmarks2`

The problem is this also deletes entries containing custom thumbnails like this:

`"Thumbnail": "chrome://vivaldi-data/local-image/aa0d8713-99c6-4fcb-a725-a29235c4e8b0",`

So the question is, how would I remove *only* the Thumbnail entries containing or starting with the string `data:image`?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with JQ (or JSON for that matter), so apologies if I'm not using the correct terms above. I also wasn't able to find another answer exactly matching this specific case.

Comment: I don't know much `jq` either but a workaround would be to use `jq` just to pretty print the json, then use `sed` to remove the lines containing `"Thumbnail": "data:image`? That might still be valid json?

Comment: @SamBob Yes, `sed` would be good, but for some reason it seems to break the JSON, and clears everything until it gets a new copy from the Sync server. While using the `jq` tool works, not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
del(recurse | objects | select(has("Thumbnail")) .Thumbnail | select(startswith("data:image")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another constraint `startswith("data:image") | not` and `select` to keep only the elements whose `.key` does not match `or` whose `.value` does not start that way, resulting in: `select((.key | test("Thumbnail") | not) or (.value | startswith("data:image") | not))`. You could even apply De Morgan's laws and simplify it to `select(((.key | test("Thumbnail")) and (.value | startswith("data:image"))) | not)`.

However, there's a simpler approach: Assuming the overall structure is an array along the lines of

```
[
  {
    "date_added": "13215828073144281",
    "guid": "3ace3174-ea60-42c5-88cf-e535a150ae38",
    ...
  },
  {
    "date_added": "13215828073144282",
    "guid": "3ace3174-ea60-42c5-88cf-e535a150ae39",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Then simply call

```
jq 'map(del(.meta_info.Thumbnail | select(startswith("data:image"))))' Bookmarks
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried the simplified approach, but jq just dumps core, I get that a lot when testing stuff and not sure if it's Cygwin or something else.

Comment: The others work but all those parentheses get confusing ;)

`jq 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(select((.key | test("Thumbnail") | not) or (.value | startswith("data:image") | not))) else . end)' Bookmarks`

Comment: Maybe your overall structure isn't a simple array, then. Unfortunately, I don't know vivaldi's export data structures, I just tried to take out the complexity of your `walk` and just apply a `map`. If the structure is, however, complex enough, then go with @oguz's approach using `recurse` which to some extent is similar to your `walk` but then utilizes the same technique as I do (`select` and `del`).

Comment: Yeah, it's a complex structure, several layers deep. For an example (in case you're interested), see: https://pastebin.com/S3r62qjk .
I added the NRK bookmark there with a thumbnail.